# What's the most efficient way to convert between two implementations of the same types?

Tags: c++

For example, I have a QMatrix4x4 and I have a Ogre::Matrix4.

Converting back and forth from QMatrix to Ogre::Matrix4 is a bit tedious, I would like to know if there are any solid solutions?

Right now I'm simply copying each element over in a for loop, any suggestions?

Comment: Manual copying seems solid to me. What's your problem with that? Performance?

Comment: Yeah, just trying to formulate different ways. A 4x4 matrix isn't the smallest data type, but if this is the only way then I'll seek ways where I don't have to convert all too often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11, if both types are *layout-compatible*, you can simply `reinterpret_cast` between them. Example:

```
#include <cassert>

struct X{
  int a, b, c, d;
};

struct Y{
  int arr[4];
};

int main(){
  X x{0, 1, 2, 3};
  Y& y = reinterpret_cast<Y&>(x);
  assert(y.arr[2] == 2);
}
```

(I hope I got the example right; [live on Ideone](http://ideone.com/KRG8g).)

The problem with this approach is that you'll need to dig into the internals of the implementations, which might not be stable over different releases even. As such, simply copying is likely the best (as in most portable / known / solid) approach.

One thing though: I personally don't know which interfaces the types in question offer, Ogre might also offer algorithms that don't directly operate on a `Matrix4` but on an (2D) array aswell. Check the API documentation.

Comment: AFAIK `struct X` and `struct Y` are not layout-compatible (as the standard defines it), they don't share the same number of non-static members in the same exact order of declaration.

Comment: @refp: Ugh, I feared something like that. I'm not wading all too deeply in those parts of the standard. Gotta recheck on that...

Comment: I'm 99% sure that there isn't any special case mentioned in the standard regarding the similarties between `struct .. {T a[2];}` and `struct .. {T a; T b;}`, holla if you find anything.

Comment: @refp: Yeah, found nothing on that. Got a nice example that isn't just declaring the same type twice with different names? :P (I know of [Boost mutant](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Boost_mutant), maybe I'll just use that.)

Comment: in practice it should work. the first element of a POD struct is guaranteed to be at the same address as the struct. and with PODness comes no access specifiers, which means increasing addresses for the individual members. finally, it would have to be a really perverse compiler to introduce padding between successive `int`s, even if it's allowed to do that (it is). so, it should work.